# MySQL results count

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the number of results from mysql query using php, this is what I tried:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT email FROM `appointments` WHERE email = '" . $email . "'");
$results = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $results++;
}
return $results;
```

The issue with this is that it always returns 9

I did a `print_r` on my `$query` and returned this:

`mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 9 [type] => 0 )`

My question is, how do I get the number of results of mysql query using php.

I suppose I can use `SELECT COUNT(*)` unless, someone else has a better idea.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: yes, select count(*) is the proper way to go, unless you're using the current result set some place else

Comment: You can use `mysqli_num_rows($result);` But `COUNT(*)` is also good

Comment: See also [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php). Incrementing a variable while fetching all rows just to get a count is probably the least efficient methods of doing this.

Comment: `FOUND_ROWS()`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: not familiar with `mysqli` api but isn't `$query->num_rows` is giving total number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT email FROM `appointments` WHERE email = '" . $email . "'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
return mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: If all you want is to count rows - it's a silly idea to fetch all the data from DB. Especially when they are all exactly the same values.

Comment: There are different ways to solve this issue. Assuming that he needs the count as well as the values in the table, my answer will be more appropriate. However, if he requires only the count of the row then the other answer will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM `appointments` WHERE email = '" . $email . "'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

return $row['num'];
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT('email')` - `email` is a column, not a value.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good catch.  To Ashlique:  You want to remove the quotes around email if you didn't understand what Fred is pointing out. `COUNT(*)` is typically a safe bet.

Comment: Tell me what is wrong if I specify a column name instead of COUNT(*)?

Comment: It makes sense to change it to `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @AshiqueCM.  There isn't anything wrong with `email` but you had `'email'` which means it is evaluating it as text, not as the column.

Comment: * always will take much time for execution than specify the column which I learned, correct me if I'm wrong. I learn do not used select *, instead of specify columns.

Comment: @Devon: funny thing is that it does not matter in this case. `COUNT('email')` would work without any issues as well. And even more - `COUNT` with constant value in this case is better than `COUNT` with a column name.

Comment: @Ashique C M: you are wrong. `COUNT(*)` has nothing to do with what you're talking about. It's a shortcut for `COUNT(1)` which does not require any additional comparisons to evaluate.

Comment: @zerkms Can you elaborate on that? `COUNT('email')` - email being a string; there's something I'm obviously not aware of. Aren't we counting column(s)?

Comment: @zerkms: Good point.  I guess it doesn't affect it to put a string inside count().  I hadn't ever tried it before, I guess this would be more an argument about semantics rather than functionality then.

Comment: @Fred -ii-: `COUNT('email')` - as soon as `COUNT` sees a constant - it evaluates if it's null or not once. Whereas for `COUNT(email)` it will do that for every row (not sure if mysql is smart enough to not do that with a given predicate though). "Aren't we counting column(s)" --- `COUNT` function accepts an arbitrary *expression*. It must not be a column, and may be literally any valid mysql expression, including a string.

Comment: @Devon: the most *semantically correct* solution here is `COUNT(*)` then, since we are counting *rows*.

Comment: but guys see the url there is huge difference in execution time : http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: @Ashique C M: there is. So?